# Derivative of the map $\mathbb{R}^9 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ $f(A)=A A^{T}-I$ Has Linearly Independent Columns When $A$ Orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, manifolds, orthogonal-matrices

I am attempting to show that the derivative of the map $\mathbb{R}^9 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ $f(A)=A A^{T}-I$ has linearly independent columns when $A$ is an orthogonal matrix. I know

$$ d f_A(B)=B A^T+A B^T $$

for any 3 by 3 matrix $B$.

Taking $A\in \mathcal{O}(3)$,

$$ d f_A(B)=B A^T+A B^T=B A^{-1}+(B A^{-1})^{-1}, $$

but I can't seem to do any meaningful manipulation to this equation.

I am doing an exercise in Munkres and this is given as a hint, so that I can then apply another result to show the 3 by 3 orthogonal matrices are a manifold in $\mathbb{R}^9$.

Comment: I guess you are also taking $B\in O(3)$? Maybe it is useful to take $B= CA$ and then $df_A(CA)= C+C^T$.

Comment: This is essentially Severin's hint (posted while I was writing this comment) in a different guise: Fix a $3 \times 3$ matrix $B$. Since $f(A B) = A B B^\top A^\top - I$, if $B$ is orthogonal then $f(A B) = f(A)$. In particular, the rank of the derivative $df_A$ is the same at all orthogonal matrices $A$, and thus it suffices to compute the rank at just one, e.g., $A = I$.

Comment: Would it then be as simple as proving $d f_A$ is a surjection onto the 3 by 3 symmetric matrices?

Comment: @Saru yes it would